# Why does sbt not choose the most recent dependency version within range?

Tags: scala, sbt

in a **build.sbt** we can declare a range for a dependency; for example:

```
libraryDependencies += groupID %% "mylib" % "[2.0,)"
```

There are (in my case) multiple packages that fall within this range (I have 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4 and even some more exotic versions like 2.0.1.dev and 2.0.3-dev of *mylib* available in my repository).

When I try to build this project, `sbt` consequently chooses version *2.0.2* for no apparent reason. I would expect him to take the biggest number within the range, but he never does. Here are the requirements I tried and the version he selected (so only when specifying an exact version number does he select a more recent version):

```
revision range      |    version selected
-----------------------------------------
[2.0,)              |    2.0.2
[2.0.0,)            |    2.0.2
]2.0,)              |    2.0.2
2.0.+               |    2.0.2
latest.integration  |    2.0.2
2.0.3               |    2.0.3
2.0.4               |    2.0.4
```

I have already tried the following workarounds:

- removing the local **~/.sbt** and **~/.ivy2** directories
- running `sbt -no-share -sbt-dir /tmp/sbt -ivy-dir /tmp/ivy` to avoid any caching effect
- searching my home directory for any file containing **mylib** in the name; only found ind **~/.ivy2**
- I have run most of my tests with **sbt 0.13.16**, but I have tried with 0.13.15 and 0.13.17
- Note that all my builds run each time in a clean clone of my git repository; so no **target** directory remains.
- the versions 2.0.2, 2.0.3 and 2.0.4 of mylib contain the same code and dependencies (I republished them for testing purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (for once) does not seem to reside in `sbt`.

I tried with **sbt 1.2.1** and range `2.1.x`. Now sbt complains that he cannot find this dependency; and he lists the available versions:

```
[warn] ==== my-maven-repo: tried
[warn] http://my-server/nexus/repository/my-repo/eu/company/mylib_2.12/[revision]/mylib_2.12-[revision].pom
[warn]   [2.0.2, 2.0.2-dev.20180719.16.55.39.develop.dc3a706, 2.0.1-dev.20180719.16.49.57.develop.dc3a706, 2.0.1-dev.20180719.16.42.31.develop.dc3a706, 2.0.1.dev.20180719.16.31.59.develop.dc3a706]
```

so strangely he does not list all packages available on my nexus-maven repository.
After deleting one package using the nexus interface; it seems like this list was now complete.

So the real problem seems to be that `sbt publish` to a nexus repository does not recreate the index in that repository.

## Workaround

I have created a custom **sbt-publish-wrapper** script to force `nexus` to recreate the repository metadata when publishing a new library:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# just run sbt publish with the passed arguments as-is
sbt $@ publish
# now make sure the repository on nexus is re-indexed
# this triggers a task to recreate metadata for all maven repositories. This task was manually configured in nexus.
# the id was obtained running `curl -v -u admin:***** -X GET http://my-company/nexus/service/rest/v1/tasks`
# the recreate-maven-repos needs only the nx-tasks-run privilege
curl -q -u recreate-maven-repos:recreate -X POST http://my-company/nexus/service/rest/v1/tasks/c42ab5f5-4bd6-4ed3-b2f1-d061c24a9b90/run
```

Comment: I see a lot of people who have run into this problem, but has anyone come up with a simple fix that I can put in my publishTo target that will just recreate the metadata xml file?

Comment: @CarlZmola. I have implemented a workaround since then. I have added that workaround in my answer.