# how to force sonatype nexus 3 to recreate maven-metadata.xml for maven repository?

Tags: maven, sbt, nexus

I use `sbt` to publish new artifacts to a nexus-maven2 repository (my-maven-repo). The new artefacts appear in the nexus interface. Another sbt project uses these artefacts. When using exact requirements; he finds those, but when using a range; he fetches the list of available artifacts and that list is never up to date.

Methods / workarounds I have tried and their result:

- **NOT WORKING:** using the nexus interface --> repositories --> my-maven-repo --> rebuild index
- **NOT WORKING**: `curl -v -u user:pass -X DELETE http://my-server/nexus/service/local/metadata/repositories/my-maven-repo/content` (error: Http method DELETE is not supported by this URL )
- **WORKING** : **deleting** another artefact in the same repository. But this is **not** really a nice solution; I don't want to start deleting artefacts AND this would require admin privileges.

NOTES:

- tested with different `sbt` versions, this does not seem to be an `sbt` issue; see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51824517/2082964)
- nexus version 3.4.0-02
- using the BETA API I can find the new versions (`curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://my-server/nexus/service/siesta/rest/beta/search?repository=my-maven-repo&name=mylib_2.12&version=2.4.0'`); but `sbt` still does not find them when not specifying the exact version number.

**EDIT**: 
The **incomplete** list can be obtained using `wget http://my-server/nexus/repository/my-maven-repo/org/company/mylib_2.12/maven-metadata.xml`

**EDIT2**
upgrading to nexus-3.13 did not solve the problem.

Comment: First I recommend to upgrade to the most recent version of Nexus 3...(3.13.?)

Comment: @khmarbaise: upgrade was done, the same issue remains

Comment: Have you configured to run a task in Admin area?

Comment: @khmarbaise have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a **workaround** using the new API present in nexus repository manager-3.13:

- (using the web interface): create a new task to recreate ALL hosted maven repositories (`Repair - Rebuild Maven repository metadata (maven-metadata.xml)`)
- `curl -v -u user:pass -X GET http://my-server/nexus/service/rest/v1/tasks` to get the id of this task
- `curl -v -u user:pass -X POST http://my-server/nexus/service/rest/v1/tasks/c42ab5f5-4bd6-4ed3-b2f1-d061c24a9b90/run` to trigger the recreation of all maven-metadata.xml

Downsides:

- need of administrator privileges
- need of an additional step after `sbt publish` to make sure maven-metadata.xml is up to date

Comment: In a maven repository it's the responsibility of the tool doing the deployment to update the maven-metadata.xml files.  That's the way Maven works.  Sounds like something is wrong with the way you're deploying these jars, it should not be necessary to have Nexus rebuild these files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled onto this with the same problem and thought I'd share my solution. We have an application where we upload artifacts to a Nexus repository using the REST API, and this does not create the proper maven-metadata.xml files. For example, for com/test/artifact version 2.0.0, it creates com/test/artifact/2.0.0/maven-metadata.xml but not com/test/artifact/maven-metadata.xml. gschizas' answer above was helpful in finding a solution, but his answer is for the rebuildIndex task, which is not the one you want. You need the 'Repair - Rebuild Maven repository metadata' task. Unfortunately there is no REST API to create tasks, only to list and run. I too monitored network traffic while creating this task. Here's a solution which is working for me in the form of a bash snippet:

```
# create the task
response=$(curl \
  --silent \
  --fail \
  --user $NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"action":"coreui_Task","method":"create","data":[{"id":"NX.coreui.model.Task-1","typeId":"repository.maven.rebuild-metadata","enabled":true,"name":"rebuild maven metadata","alertEmail":"","notificationCondition":"FAILURE","schedule":"manual","properties":{"repositoryName":"maven-hosted","groupId":"","artifactId":"","baseVersion":"","rebuildChecksums":"false"},"recurringDays":[],"startDate":null,"timeZoneOffset":"+00:00"}],"type":"rpc","tid":0}' \
  http://$NEXUS_SERVER/service/extdirect)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  taskid=$(echo $response | jq -r .result.data.id)
  if [[ "$taskid" != "null" ]]; then
    # run the task
    curl \
      --silent \
      --user $NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD \
      --header 'accept: application/json' \
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --request 'POST' \
      --data '' \
      http://$NEXUS_SERVER/service/rest/v1/tasks/${taskid}/run
  fi
fi
```

We're using Nexus OSS 3.41.

Answer (score 0):

I cheated by monitoring network traffic, and I ended up with the following:

```
curl \
    --silent \
    --user $NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"action":"coreui_Repository","method":"rebuildIndex","data":[$NEXUS_REPOSITORY],"type":"rpc","tid":0}' \
    http://$NEXUS_SERVER/service/extdirect
```

This does work for me. Even though "tid" is supposed to be some auto-incrementing number, but it does not seem to matter.